# Meaning of 立てる in どうやって皆を立てたい、立てれるとこ立てよう

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm trying to translate the actor's speech from [this clip](https://youtu.be/KKD6OwbpbN4?t=54s).

Now I got stuck at 0:54 where he said

> もう本当に今回やっぱ縁下(えんのした)として、元々やっぱ原作って前も言ったように描かれていない部分がすごい多いんで、その分、やっぱり、皆をどうやってサポートしようかな、**どうやって皆を立てたい、立てれるとこ立てようかな** とかすごい考えた時に、まあ本当に微々たる所でやってくしか無いんだなと思って

I was wondering about the meaning 立て in the above sentence. I did look up the dictionary and the reason I thought 立て = to stand is because they are the stage actor, so they need to think about how they should stand on the stage.

At first I thought he meant

> 皆をどうやってサポートしようかな、どうやって皆を立てたい

= How should I support everyone?, How I want everyone to stand?

> 立てれるとこ立てようかな とかすごい考えた時に

= Where can everyone stand?

and I couldn't grasp the meaning of the rest.

According to the comment below, I assume that 立て here do not mean "to stand",

and each of them probably has a different meaning?

but there are several meanings on both [Jishou](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A6) and on [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%82%88%E3%81%86)
I still could not make any senses out of these meaning, which is why I decided to reach out for help.

Comment: Did you look up the word?  It is being used for a very common meaning.  Forget "to stand".

Comment: See definition #6 in jisho: http://jisho.org/search/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B and Weblio: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BA%BA%E3%82%92%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B

Comment: Well.., isn't it understandable to have a trouble knowing what to look for in dictionaries?

Comment: 立てたい, 立てれる & 立てよう are all have single root 立てる。So that it
 is possible to say どうやって皆を立てたい => How should I do to [respect] everyone?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto That makes more sense now, but I was still confused about the latter part 立てれるとこ立てようかな.   Is it something like "How can I do now to respect them and How will I respect them?

Comment: "かな" as ending means "wonder", 立てれる here represents "to respect" & 立てよう more likely used for "shall I do/make" (lit: "I wonder anything I can do to respect"), and I think "how will I respect them" is preferred over "how can I do now to respect them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 立てる here means "to make (someone) look good".

> 皆をどうやってサポートしようかな、どうやって皆を立てたい

どうやって皆を立てたい is ungrammatical. I think he meant to say どうやって皆を立てようかな "How can I make others/everyone look good?" or maybe どうかして皆を立てたい "I want to make others/everyone look good in some way".

As you know, どうやって～～ようかな means "I wonder how I should/can..." "How can/should I...?"

> 立てれるとこ立てようかな とかすごい考えた時に

立てれるとこ is a colloquial, collapsed form of 立て**ら**れるとこ(ろ).
立てられるところ = The part (in them) that I can make look good (立てられる modifies ところ.)
The られる is potential.

> 『皆をどうやってサポートしようかな、どうやって皆を（立てたい→立てようかな）、立て（ら）れるとこ（を）立てようかな』とかすごい考えた時に...

*lit.* When I thought/wondered hard "How can I support them, how can I make them look good, how can I make the part (in them) that I can make look good look good"...
→ When I really thought/wondered "How can I support them, how can I make them look good, how should I make them look good when I can / as much as I can"...

Comment: The above comment said this 立てる has a very common meaning. May I ask for future references how did you guys know 立てる here did not mean "to stand" like what is the main pinpoint here?

Comment: We know it cos we are more often in need to 立てる others in Japan, maybe?? Like.. we are supposed to 立てる our superiors, sempai, the elderly, mother-in-law...